# SQL variable parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I need to merge data into different columns of table. I need to use stored proc to merge these data.
I have a(i = 1 to x), b, c and d as parameters

a(i = 1 to x) parameters depend on the user entry...

the other thing I need to check is at

```
if a(y) = b
then update b and c to table 1
else delete data from table 1 and update values a(y) to b into 4 different tables
Here y is some value in between 1 to x
```

should i do multiple dataconnections or use one data connection and do everything in sql?? what is the best way to tackle this problem...

If second option please samples would be a great help... Just sql side would be great!!!

Comment: What have you tried? you also should be more clear about what you want to happen

Comment: I am lost how/where to start.... I was thinking about hitting the stored proc multiple times but I have doubts about hitting it too many times...

For Stored Proc I could not even start how to take the delimited list and separate so that it can do "for each" for every values

Comment: Can you not determine `a(y) = b` in your application and then choose to run 1 sproc which represents `update b and c to table 1` or a different sproc that represents the *else logic*

Comment: there will be atleast 4-5 a(y), so checking that would run the stored proc 4 times... is it good in performance point?

Comment: actually 4-5 times is nothing, sql-server can cope with far more hits concurrently

Comment: Oh Ok Thanks!!! i would probably run stored proc multiple times...

Comment: Any ways the passing of multiple values to sql-server has been asked so many times http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328134/pass-in-dynamic-number-of-parameters-to-a-stored-procedure so you could execute it once if you needed too

Comment: check **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11490089/1499112)**